# How can I close current ul and start new ul using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

Please see code below: There is a `ul` span generated dynamically using PHP code. After the 2nd span I close the current `ul` and start a new `ul`. How can I do this using jquery?

```
<ul class="menutop" id="menutop">
  <span id="show_dynamic_0">    
    <li class="item1 active root" id="item1 active root">
      <a id="a-1309599451911317" class="orphan item bullet" href="http://localhost/health_phase2/">
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </span> 
  <span id="show_dynamic_1">    
    <li class="item2 root" id="item2 root">
      <a id="a-1309599451912733" class="orphan item bullet" href="/health_phase2/index.php">
        <span>News Feed</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </span> 
  <!--Here I want to end menutop ul. After than start new ul. Means end current ul and start new ul --> 
  <!-- </ul><ul>  -->
  <span id="show_dynamic_2">    
    <li class="item6 root" id="item6 root">
      <a id="a-1309599451912287" class="orphan item bullet" href="/health_phase2/index.php?option=com">
        <span>Video</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </span> 
  <span id="show_dynamic_3">    
    <li class="item7 root" id="item7 root">
      <a id="a-1309599451913684" class="orphan item bullet" href="/health_phase2/index.php?option=com_content">
        <span>Interviews</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </span> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid.  Only `li` elements are allowed as children of `ul` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could `detach` the elements after `index > 1`, wrap them in a `<ul>` and insert them after the previous `<ul>`:

```
$('#menutop > span:gt(1)').detach().wrapAll('<ul />').parent().insertAfter("#menutop");
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/eWVvQ/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$("#menutop").after( $("<ul/>").append($("#show_dynamic_1").nextAll()) );
```

What it does is the following:
- Create a new ul
- "Cut" the spans that are after #show_dynamic_1 and insert them into the created ul
- Insert the new ul after the #menutop ul.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the way it should be in your HTML code. First of all you don't need to wrap `<li>`'s in `<span>`'s.

...and what is this workaround for?

If you walk through an array in PHP or an object in JavaScript, you can say that you want to have the `</ul><ul>` rendered between your 2nd and your 3rd `<span>`.